# Как реализовать text-to-speech на Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, text-to-speech

Мой вопрос идет ниже. Сначала короткое введение.

Сейчас я учу Java (использую Эклипс) и наткнулся на следующий учебный пример - который представляет собой вариацию программы text-to-speech (TTS) на Java. Собственно сама программа лежит тут  [Lesson01_Speech.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/practicaljava/Lesson01_Speech.zip).

Суть программы сводится к следующему::

1. Связать проект с библиотекой `JLayer`
     для воспроизведения mp3 с java (Using the library `jl1.0.1.jar`).
2. Создать экземпляр класса: `GoogleTextToSpeech gtts = new GoogleTextToSpeech()`.
3. Использовать метод: `gtts.say ("Hello everybody", "en")`. Первый аргумент фраза для произнесения, второй - язык.

Я добавил в прогу свои комментарии (на английском) и закомментировал явно лишнею строчку, теперь прога выглядит так  (`Main` class):

```
package com.example.TTS; // package of class Main

import com.example.TTS.GoogleTextToSpeech; // import class GoogleTextToSpeech

public class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GoogleTextToSpeech gtts = new GoogleTextToSpeech(); // make instance gtts
    gtts.say("Hello dear friends", "en"); // use method say
//  gtts.say("Bonjour mon amis!", "fr");
  }
}
```

`GoogleTextToSpeech` class:

```
package com.example.TTS; // package of class GoogleTextToSpeech

import java.io.InputStream; // import  classes from Java library
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player; // import class from jl1.0.1.jar

public class GoogleTextToSpeech {
  private static String ENCODING = "UTF-8"; //make constants and assign values to them
  private static String URL_BEGINNING = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=";
  private static String URL_QUERY = "&q=";
  private static String URL_TL = "&tl=";
  private static String USER_AGENT_LITERAL = "User-Agent";
  private static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/4.7";

  public void say( String phrase, String lang ) {
    
    try {
      //Make full URL
      phrase=URLEncoder.encode(phrase, ENCODING); //assign value to variable with name 'phrase' by use method encode from class URLEncoder 
      String sURL = URL_BEGINNING + ENCODING + URL_TL + lang + URL_QUERY + phrase; //assign value to variable sURL 
          URL url = new URL(sURL); // make instance url with constructor
          
          //Create connection
          URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection(); //assign value to variable urlConn 
          HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn; //Declaring a httpUrlConn variable of type HttpURLConnection and assigning it a value to some variable urlConn (which is previously reduce to  HttpURLConnection)
          httpUrlConn.addRequestProperty(USER_AGENT_LITERAL, USER_AGENT);// use method 
          
          //Create stream
          InputStream mp3WebStream = urlConn.getInputStream();//create instance and assign it a value
          
          //Play stream
          Player plr = new Player(mp3WebStream); //create instance plr with constructor
          plr.play(); //use method
    }
      //use exception with name ex
      catch (Exception ex) { 
      ex.printStackTrace(); //use method
    }
  }
}
```

Стартую программу путем выбора `Run as → Java Application` на `Main.java`.

И имею следующий вывод ( в эклипс консоли):

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://translate.google.com/translate_tts%3Fie%3DUTF-8%26tl%3Den%26q%3DHello%2Bdear%2Bfriends&q=EgRbegWvGJ3FldEFIhkA8aeDS952qU94sbK8DAgP55pH8cbMicZdMgFy
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at com.example.TTS.GoogleTextToSpeech.say(GoogleTextToSpeech.java:32)
at com.example.TTS.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы эта программа работала?

И еще вопрос:

Когда я запускаю свою программу, я получаю

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://translate.google.com/translate_tts%3Fie%3DUTF-8%26tl%3Den%26q%3DHello%2Bdear%2Bfriends&q=EgRbegWvGJ3FldEFIhkA8aeDS952qU94sbK8DAgP55pH8cbMicZdMgFy
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at com.example.TTS.GoogleTextToSpeech.say(GoogleTextToSpeech.java:32)
    at com.example.TTS.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

затем я нажимаю `HttpURLConnection.java:1894` или `HttpURLConnection.java:1492`, и я получаю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] или [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  
Мой проводник пакетов выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Если вы нажмете на GoogleTextToSpeech.class или на Main.class в Navigator в Eclipse, вы увидите то же самое. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Эклипс по какой-то причине не может открывать классы. Как это исправить? То есть где-то нужно что-то предписывать?
  
Возможно, мне нужно сделать что-то вроде этого: Задайте следующие переменные среды пользователя:

`JAVA_HOME: C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_152 JDK_HOME:% JAVA_HOME% JRE_HOME:% JAVA_HOME% \ jre  CLASSPATH:.;% JAVA_HOME% \ lib;% JAVA_HOME% \ jre \ lib  PATH: ваши уникальные записи;% JAVA_HOME% \ bin`

Когда JDK установлен, он добавляет в переменную системной среды Path запись C: \ ProgramData \ Oracle \ Java \ javapath ; Поэтому лучше всего удалить C: \ ProgramData \ Oracle \ Java \ javapath; из переменной окружения Path, чтобы иметь согласованную среду?

Если я правильно перевел это:

Set the following user environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152
JDK_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%\jre
CLASSPATH: .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
PATH: your-unique-entries;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Make sure that the longish your-unique-entries does not contain any other references to another Java installation folder.

Optional recommendations:

When JDK is installed, it adds to the system environment variable Path an entry `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;`. I anecdotally noticed that the links in that directory didn't get updated during an JDK installation update. So it's best to remove `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` from the Path system environment variable in order to have a consistent environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы не стал вызывать всякие непонятные сервисы со своего сайта. *Лучше запускать **свою** прогу со **своего** сервера.* И вот почему:

В вашем случае ошибка в строке

```
at com.example.TTS.GoogleTextToSpeech.say(GoogleTextToSpeech.java:32)
at com.example.TTS.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

далее по стектрейсу вызывается код самой библиотеки [MP3 Decoder/player/converter](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javazoom/jlayer),

который открывает подключение к странице [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20dear%20friends),

которая:

- в заголовках ответа содержит [X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)
- перенаправляет на страницу с [капчей](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/)
- возвращает статус [503 Service Unavailable](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#503)

---

*Что делать!*

---

**Самому нарезать mp3 со звуками букв**

На каждую букву нужно иметь:

- мужской, женский и детский голос
- высокий, средний и низкий тон
- штук 10 рандомных шумов

таким образом получается `3 * 3 * 10 = 90` вариантов на каждую букву.

*А ещё можно и цифры добавить!*